# "warning: comparison between pointer and integer" when comparing strings

Tags: c

I'm trying to compare two inputs, `username` and `password`, with a hard-coded char (`'a'`):

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void login();

int main(void){
  login();
}

void login(){
    char username[100];
    char pass[100]; 

    int i = 0;
    while( i < 3){
        printf("Enter the username : ");
        scanf("%c", &username);
        printf("Password : ");
        scanf("%c", &pass);

        printf("%c %c \n", username, pass);

        if ((username == 'a') && (pass == 'a')){
            printf("You are sucessfull login into your account");
            BilaDahLogin();
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("The username or password incorrect\nTry again\n");
            i += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
MyCProjects.c: In function 'login':
MyCProjects.c:63:17: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   if ((username == 'a') && (pass == 'a')){
                 ^~
MyCProjects.c:63:34: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   if ((username == 'a') && (pass == 'a')){
                                  ^~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. `username` and `pass` are arrays (i.e. pointers) so you shouldn't pass their address with the `&` operator.

Secondly, since it seems you would like the username and password to be more than one character long, you should use string comparisons from string.h.

```c
#include "string.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void login()
{
    char username[100];
    char pass[100]; 

    int i = 0;
    while( i < 3){
        printf("Enter the username : ");
        scanf("%s", username); //username is an array and therefore a pointer to the first element so no & is necessary
        printf("Password : ");
        scanf("%s", pass); //pass is an array and therefore a pointer to the first element so no & is necessary

        printf("%s %s \n", username, pass);

        if ((0 == strcmp(username, "a")) &&  //use string comparison so can comapre more than one character
            (0 == strcmp(pass, "a")))
        {
            printf("You are sucessfull login into your account\n");
            //BilaDahLogin();
            break;

        }
        else{
            printf("The username or password incorrect\nTry again\n");
            i += 1;
        }
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    login();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should include the needed libraries if you have not done so already, which are stdio.h and string.h. Second, if you want the user to give input using a scanf you should replace `scanf("%c", &username);` and `scanf("%c", &pass);` with `scanf("%s", &username);` and `scanf("%s", &pass);` respectively. Later on you want to print username and password using `printf("%c %c \n", username, pass);`. Again, change that to `printf("%s %s \n", username, pass);`. Lastly, when you want to compare strings you have to use the "strcmp" command, so change `if ((username == 'a') && (pass == 'a'))` to `if ((strcmp(username, "a")==0) && (strcmp(pass, "a")==0))`. After these changes your code should look something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void login(){
    char username[100];
    char pass[100]; 


    int i = 0;
    while( i < 3){
        printf("Enter the username : ");
        scanf("%s", &username);
        printf("Password : ");
        scanf("%s", &pass);

        printf("%s %s \n", username, pass);

        if ((strcmp(username, "a")==0) && (strcmp(pass, "a")==0)){
            printf("You are sucessfull login into your account");
            BilaDahLogin();
            break;

        }
        else{
            printf("The username or password incorrect\nTry again\n");
            i += 1;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `username` variable is an array of characters, and is actually a pointer to the front of this array (not a character). If you want to compare, for example, the first character in this array, you'll have to specify that with something like `username[0] == 'a'` or `*username == 'a'`.